# How to update date , but date/day should not be sat or sunday

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a Execute SQL task in SSIS, which updates date in Database to today's date+3. But if suppose today is Thursday say(18/6/2015) and jobs executes then according to update query date in Database will be update to (21/6/2015) out of which 20th and 21st are Sat and Sunday. Instead i would want the date to be updated to 23/6/2015 i.e Tuesday( excluding Sat and Sunday). Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made the following `SELECT` statement which may help you.
Using the `DATEPART` function you can discover which day of the week a sum of days will be.

`DATEPART` returns a number representing the day of the week of the date passed as parameter to the function, considering 1 is Sunday and 7 is Saturday.

```
select CASE 
         WHEN DATEPART(DW, GETDATE() + 4) = 7 THEN (SELECT GETDATE() + 6)
         WHEN DATEPART(DW, GETDATE() + 5) = 1 THEN (SELECT GETDATE() + 5)
       END As date
```

Using this example in an update statement:

```
UPDATE <your table> 
SET    dateofanything = (CASE 
                           WHEN DATEPART(DW, GETDATE() + 3) = 7 THEN (SELECT GETDATE() + 5)
                           WHEN DATEPART(DW, GETDATE() + 3) = 1 THEN (SELECT GETDATE() + 4)
                         END As date)
```